# Is there a way to show the gesture navigation bar instead of the 3-button navigation bar in the layout editor in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using android studio 2021.2.1 patch 1. I have looked around about this issue but it seems like no one has ever asked about it and maybe google didn't even add this option at all? Seems like a huge oversight on google's part if that were the case considering proper gesture navigation has been out since 2019 (Android 10).

[Here's what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKAxk.png)

Answer (score 0):

I mean, there is a way in the emulator (go to the settings app, navigate to the "System" bar, click "Gestures," then "System Navigation," where you can find a list to switch to Gesture Navigation). I'm not sure about having navigation in the Layout Editor though. Hope this helps!

Comment: I know you can do that in the emulator. I was asking specifically about the layout editor because it seems like there's just no way to see your app layout in real-time with gesture navigation